# Is there a way to set variables resolving to path in terminal e.g: ~ is for /home/<username>

Tags: gnome-terminal

Just to clarify: I know we can set environment variables with export command like 
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/..`

For environment variables, we need to use '$' sign in starting and we can not explore the path further using 'tab' key. I am just wondering that as `~` is set to path `/home/<username>`, is there a way to set variables to path in the same pattern  where we can also use 'tab' key to further explore the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"~" is not variable, it is "link" to $HOME and some other variables. You can read more about tilde expansion in [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion).

With variables and aliases, like $HOME, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to perform the readline function `shell-expand-line`.

Also, if you are interested in rich expanding features, you might try using zsh instead of bash.

Comment: Thanks for Bash Reference Manual link. I am a beginner in bash and thought tilde(~) is also a variable. Expanding features are interesting.